# Connected App - Pre-authorized Users for Community

Tags: community, oauth2, connected-apps

I have created a Connected App that uses "OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow" to access a Community.  The App has "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" option selected under "Permitted Users".  This option however does not work with Community Login License users.  It works fine with other Salesforce License users.  For Community Login License users, the app returns an error - "user hasn't approved this consumer".

The Community profile has been added to the App and has access to the Community. It also has "API Enabled" permission.  The App has Web, Refresh_token and Chatter Api scopes selected.

Does Connected App pre-authorization work with Community users?

Comment: I know this was asked long time ago, but have you checked that the community profile is assigned to the connected app after enable the pre-authorized option? I recently tried the same and didn't had issues, I am not setting api enabled under the community user profile in my case, and the scopes on the connected app are Web and Refresh token.